# undefined method `association' in my ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

In my ruby application , I tried to associate my table "events" with " campus " table. At the time of use f.association gave this error:

`undefined method 'association' for # < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0xbbcdbd68 >`

Follow my code. Could help me figure out what I did wrong? Thank U.

```
class Evento < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :foto
  validates_attachment_content_type :foto, :content_type => %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png image/gif)
  validates :nome, presence: true
  validates :descricao, presence: true
  validates :local, presence: true
  belongs_to :campu
end

class Campu < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :nome, presence: true
  has_many :eventos
end

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :campu %><br>
    <%= f.association :campu %>
  </div>
```

Comment: are you trying to use simple_form?

Comment: no. I using normal form, see:    <%= form_for @evento, :html => { :multipart => true} do |f| %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The f object doesn't have an association method see docs for methods available:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Presuming you want to use the association to create a field you have to use the method which specifies the field e.g.

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :campu %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :campu %>
</div>
```

Comment: how can i proceed in this case? i want to use association whitout simple_form in a view

Comment: The issue is that association is a method added by the [simple form library](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) and doesn't exist in Rails by default

Comment: Presuming you want a drop down you are going to ave to use select_tag and f.fields_for to loop though and create it your self